# Wordpress: how to show a list of pages with a meta value under any hierarchy

Tags: php, wordpress

I am coding a website where i have following page structure

```
1. -university
--India
---Delhi
----north delhi
-----university of delhi
-----Indra prastha university
---Mumbai
----south mumbai
-----university of maharashtra
--Sri lanka
--USA
---California
----University of california
```

Some of the pages have a custom field 'IsOrganization' with value 'yes'. Such pages are basically child pages of some parent page. in above example, i have all 'university' page meta value 'IsOrganization' set to 'yes'.
Now if some person is on page 'India', I need to display all pages with 'IsOrganization' with value 'yes'. 
so if a person is on Page India it should give following list irrespective of hierarchy

```
*university of delhi
*Indra prastha university
*university of maharashtra
```

if someone is browsing USA page then it should output

```
*University of california
```

I have following code but it outputs the list only if the page is an immediate child.

```
wp_list_pages( array(
    // Only pages that are children of the current page
    'child_of' => $post->ID,
    'meta_key' => 'Is organization',
    'meta_value' => 'yes',
) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got this problem solved by this code. 
for those who may need the solution:

```
<?php 

$mypages = get_pages(array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ));
foreach( $mypages as $mypage )
{
    $args = array('meta_key' => 'Is organization',
        'meta_value' =>'yes',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $mypage->ID,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```